# How to refresh the state of a SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, state, sqlconnection

I have this code:

```
if (  con.SqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken ||
      con.SqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed      
){
    con.SqlConnection.Open();
}
```

I have lost connection to the network. When i come to my `if`, then my `SqlConnection.State` still says open.

How do i refresh my state of my `SqlConnection`

Comment: If, at any time, you lose connection, I recommend disposing that connection object and instancing another one.

Comment: @IAbstract: Fair enough, so how will my app know that i have lost connection?

Comment: What is the flow here?  How long are you keeping this connection alive?

Comment: I am running a MVVM structured application, so what whould my best option be here? Create a method in SessionContext to Evaluate the state with try catch blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always monitor the state of your `SqlConnection` by using the [SqlConnection.StateChange Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452062%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: This is a programmatic thing.  Unless someone calls Close or Dispose the event wont fire.

Comment: @Nix: ...or calls Open  ;)  This event should fire if the connection times out as well. I have not observed any other limitations with it, e.g. dropped, lost, or broken connections, only because I've yet to have these occur.

Comment: I can confirm that if you have this as an event handler and during run time purposely try to kill to SQL connection this will NOT fire the event at all.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the few cases where you *should* rely on exceptions.

Microsoft actually recommends that you react to an exception versus check that state variable.  Think of the case where you check the variable, and then a nanosecond later the connection goes down.

I believe the two that would get thrown are `InvalidOperationException` or `SqlException`.

Comment: +1: Even with the StateChange event subscription, it may not be 100% reliable - an exception is certainly going to let you know!!!

Comment: Yea, but this issue could be avoided if he would limit the lifetime of his Connection.

Answer (score 3):

On TCP connections, there is only one guaranteed way to understand if the connection is still alive or not, it is sending a new packet to the open socket.

So as long as we assume you're connected to Sql Server through a TCP connection, this rule applies to it also. So you need to do send data and wait if an exception is raised.

```
    public bool IsConnected()
    {
        if (db == null) //db here is an Entity
            return false;

        //in my case Connection is an sqlconnection object so you can 
        //apply the same to your connection
        if (db.Database.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            return false;

        try
        {
            var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 0";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @rudolf_franek I just did! Sorry, it was my first reply so I had issues with formatting text.

Answer (score 1):

The lazy way: "**SELECT 0**". If the command fails, the connection state is updated to "Closed"

```
if (DBConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
   try
   {
      using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DBConn))
      {
         cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 0";
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   }
   Catch
   {
      DBConn.Close(); \\Declare the connection dead.
   }
}
```